# Image is not loading in CardMedia in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have used an image as an object with a http link and also and image from the project source folder but it is not showing in the project.

Card and everything is loading up but image is not loading.

image location is public/assests/image

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Products from './components/Products/Products';

function App(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Products />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Products.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import Product from './Product/Product';
const products = [

    { id: 1, name: 'Shoes', description: 'Running shoes.', price: '$100', image: 'assests/image/run-asics-running-shoes-1636736175.jpeg' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Macbook', description: 'Apple Macbook', price: '$120', image: 'https://images.app.goo.gl/b8T9vFGUzQeHvRmM9' },
]



const Products = () => {

    return (
        <main>
            <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
                {products.map((product) => (

                    <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                        <Product product={product} />
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
        </main>
    )



}

export default Products;
```

Product component holding all the products
Product.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardMedia, CardContent, CardActions, Typography, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import { AddShoppingCart } from '@material-ui/icons';

import useStyles from './styles';

const Product = ({ product }) => {

    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div>


            <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardMedia className={classes.media} image='product.image' title={product.name} />
                <CardContent>
                    <div className={classes.cardContent}>
                        <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                            {product.name}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h5" >
                            {product.price}
                        </Typography>


                    </div>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                        {product.description}
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}>
                    <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart">
                        <AddShoppingCart />
                    </IconButton>
                </CardActions>
            </Card>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `image='product.image'`, which sets it to the literal string "product.image". Perhaps you meant `image={product.image}`?

```
<CardMedia
  className={classes.media}
  image={product.image}
  title={product.name}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In products array image with `id:1` is ok

but image with `id:2` does not contain correct image with HTTP link it should change to correct image link (in google image, right-click:`copy image address`)

Inside `Product.js` file, change `image` property of `CardMedia` to  `image={product.image}` and it's `style={{minHeight:300}}`

**Products**:

```
const products = [

    { id: 1, name: 'Shoes', description: 'Running shoes.', price: '$100', image: 'assets/image/run.jpeg' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Macbook', description: 'Apple Macbook', price: '$120', image: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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' },
```

]

**Product**

```
 <CardMedia image={product.image} alt={product.name} style={{minHeight:300}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the  `image='product.image'` with  `image={product.image}` and your problem solved

```
        <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={product.image} title={product.name} />
        <CardContent>
            <div className={classes.cardContent}>
                <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                    {product.name}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="h5" >
                    {product.price}
                </Typography>


            </div>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                {product.description}
            </Typography>
        </CardContent>
```